Why does Acrobat Pro show empty menus for passwords in macOS 14?
On a 2018 Mac Mini running macOS 14.1.1. I installed Acrobat Pro as a trial, and opened up a password protected PDF.
I then selected the 'protect' item from the tools left-hand 'menu', and was rewarded with an empty left-hand menu. Similarly for 'convert'.
It worked fine on my M2 MacBook Air.
What could cause this?
